# Angular custom ngModel [(...)]

Tags: angular

I have created a custom component and would like to create a custom `[(ngModel)]` for it. Say I have this in a component:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="var1"> // (first input)
<my-custom-input [injectedNgModel]="var1"><my-custom-input>
```

And in my `<my-custom-input>` I have this:

```
@Input() injectedNgModel: any;
...
<input [(ngModel)]="injectedNgModel"> // (second input)
```

Then, when you enter text in the `(first input)`, it will update the `(second input)`. But when you enter text in the `(second input)`, it doesn't change the `(first input)` which is `var1`.

**How can I make an @Input send data back to it's parent?**

What I do not want is an @Output because then the component is too busy:

`<my-custom-input [injectedNgModel]="var1" (outputNgModel)="var1">`

**I was hoping for something like `[(injectedNgModel)]="x"` but I can't get it to work like this.**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upyf32

Comment: Hi freddy i will help you../...............

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

The word **Change** does the magic for you which creates the two way data binding - Means you have `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` events to bind as `[(ngModel)]` banana like syntax

So in your case you need to have `injectedNgModel` as `@Input()` and `injectedNgModelChange` as `@Output()` event emitter

Try something like this

```
 modelValue: string;

    @Output()
    injectedNgModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Input()
    get injectedNgModel(): string {
        return this.modelValue;
    }

    set injectedNgModel(val: string) {
        this.modelValue= val;
        this.injectedNgModelChange.emit(this.modelValue);
    }
```

This creates the two way data binding to your input variable `injectedNgModel` and you will get the updated value on both parent and child components

You can access it `<my-custom-input [(injectedNgModel)]="var1">` - That's the magic for the word **Change**

In your child component you can read the get and set property like this `<input [(ngModel)]="injectedNgModel">`

Hope this helps you - Happy coding :)